# Laravel Query builder how to check if an item appears twice

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4

Okay I want to use Laravel Query builder to check if a particular user's name appears twice in a column. For example in my program when a new user registers he is randomly assigned to a user as a child of that user.  So the new user will have a field like parent_id . A user can not have more than two children so I want to query my database using the query builder to get any random user who's ID does not appear twice in the parent_id column

Comment: child user and parent user in same table **user** table ?

Comment: Yes. I don't want to use eloquent relationships. Just query builders

Comment: first select previous users who not in `paren_id` two times then randomly select one  need two queries ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these

```
User::select('id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
    ->groupBy('parent_id')
    ->having('count', '<' , 2)
    ->inRandomOrder()->first();
```

or Shorter way

```
User::select('id')->groupBy('parent_id')->havingRaw('COUNT(*) < 2')->inRandomOrder()->first();
```

Here you will get `parent_id` in random manner whose appearance in `DB` as `parent_id` is less than 2 Times

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What I was looking for!!! Thanks a lot!  Sorry one last question though. Just came up now. How will I do the same query if I have a want to do it this way. A user refers a child(new user)  but already has two children so the I want to check which of the two children does not have two children so I'll make that one a parent of the new user?

Comment: try `User::where('parent_id',$parent_id)->select('id')->groupBy('parent_id')->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')->inRandomOrder()->first();`

Comment: if record exist then that particular parent have 2 child

Comment: Thanks I appreciate. Can I also do something like -
> havingRAW('COUNT(*) > 2) so it just gives me a parent  that doesn't have two children

Answer (score 1):

```
User::where('parent_id', $someId)->count();
```

I think this is the query you are looking for. It returns the number of times an `id` is used as `parent_id`. Then you can use `if` statement to check if it is less than two or not.

You can use loop and random number generator to get the random `$someId`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion , instead of finding out through query builder its better to make 'parent_id' column as unique as well as you can do validation in function as -

```
'parent_id' => 'required|unique:users'
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That's not the context I want to use it. I'm creating a listener that listens to an new user registration event.  when a new user registers i want to assign a random user who does not have more than two children to this new user as his parent. So I'll query the database for any random user that doesn't have his ID appearing twice in the parent id field